# Is checking a process for every one minute will degrade the performance of the server?

Tags: bash

I have this below script , which actually checks if Memcache server  is down , it will start Mmecache server .

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached
# if not found - equals to 1, start it
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
else
echo "eq 0 - memcache running - do nothing"
fi
```

If  i make this script run for every 1 minute by setting it in crontab this way

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/memcached_autostart.sh
```

Will it degrade the performance of the server in any way ?? or is it okay ??

Please share your experience .

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I don't know about awfully terrible. Mildly terrible, at worst. But however terrible, we would be more useful if we gave advice on how to improve it. I'll start. Preethi, instead of running a command and then checking `$?`, use the command directly as the test in the `if`.

Comment: @Tom , Thanks that makes sense , i am new to linux , please tell me how can i include this condition in the if block itself .

Comment: You simply say `if ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached`. Even better, though, would be to use `pgrep`, and say `if pgrep -f 'memcached .* -p 11211'`, which avoids the need for a pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

It won't have a significant effect on server performance, though you need to make it silent when memcached was already running, or it will waste both server time and your time by sending you e-mail every minute.

But there are much better ways to do it. The systemd and daemontools projects are both designed to monitor services and keep them running, or if you're using sysvinit, you can add your memcached command to /etc/inittab to have sysvinit keep respawning it if it exits.

Comment: Ya thats a valid to keep it silent when its running . i am new to linux how to do it via /etc/inittab

Comment: +1 for suggesting [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [inittab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5). Other options would be [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Answer (score 2):

It will be slower than *not* running this every minute. Your code can be somewhat optimized by doing

```
pidof memcached || memcached…
```

You can also instead of daemonizing memcached do something like

```
while true ; do memcached -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody ; done
```

In which case it will be restarted after termination without polling. But you better make sure you're notified if it's restarted too often — that would mean something's gone wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample script of such code which  can apply